# How to disable Jboss-logging

Tags: hibernate, maven, logging, jboss

I want to reduce reduce enormous amount of information logged on the console by hibernate.
Here's sample:

```
21:59:20.474 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: 
org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
21:59:20.490 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry
 - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@5f150435
21:59:20.490 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry 
- Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@5f150435
```

and hundreds more ...

It happened when I got hibernate using maven. I used hibernate before, but I downloaded jars manually and I had some normal logging. This is unacceptable. Any idea how to reduce/remove that?

I tried to exclude jar with POM. But effect is the same:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You can not really dusabke the logging. What you can do is configure it to repirt only impirtant messages.

Comment: How to achieve that?

Answer (score -5):

1. don't use maven.
2. logging can be suppressed by updating {your_server_dir}/conf/jboss-log4j.xml.

Comment: You mean don't use maven at all? Man it's a useful tool :)
Thing that I don't run my app on server, I'm doing it using standalone jar for now. Other solution?

Comment: In your case: don't use tool you don't understand. In general - maven is horrible since you loose control over your environment. Hibernate uses log4j for logging. Find your log4j configuration and update it so that unwanted log messages are suppressed. Such a file can be called log4j.properties, log4j.xml, jboss-log4j.xml, ..., depending on your application server/packaging.

Comment: I'm learning it. I don't even have my log4j.properties or any other you mentioned.

Comment: if you then scan your output JAR file. If it does not contain it then you need to create your own and define proper logging configuration. If some libs bring their own log4j configuration with themselves or via maven deps then you are in trouble. some manual post processing of the JAR file would be needed to replace the log4j config.